# Passing data between next pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to pass data between next js pages , large amount of user filled data including image . How can I achieve that?

I tried to look for nextjs docs but I couldn't find any solution

Comment: Did you try storing data in localStorage? Or check if this [How to persist data in nextjs app?](https://dev.to/thangphan37/how-to-persist-data-in-nextjs-app-5c4i) works for you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: According [react state management 2023](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/awesome-react-state-management), you could use react-redux for global store.

Answer (score 0):

A small number of parameters are passed through router. If it is a picture, it is better to use vuex

Comment: May I just ask, why do you recommend an opinionated state management library for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use global [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or implement a state management library like Redux or Zustand etc.

Comment: The problem is images also needed to be stored but on redux doc only serializable data should be stored

Comment: You'll need to save images in a directory(public  assets) and save image location path in data and retrieve image on another page by using its location.